# Mongoose Like Operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Below code does not work and returns an empty array. What is wrong with it:

```
const user = mongoose.model('user', {
    firstName: String
});

async function usersBySearch(search) {
    return await user.find({firstName: '/' + search + "/"});
};
```

Comment: you can use `user.find({firstName:  search});` no need for adding `""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `$regex`

```
user.find( { 'firstName' : { '$regex' : search, '$options' : 'i' } } )
```

where options : i will do a case insensitive match

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/